# Xcode 4.2: Detach a project from repository

Tags: svn, xcode4.2

I want to detach my project from Subversion and upload it again - as if it were a new project.

The only problem: Where can I detach the project from subversion? I just deleted the svn-subdirectories, but the project still knows from somewhere, that it is connected to a repository. Seems to be true love :-)

Where its the setting, to detach it?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the repository root on subversion server and delete the project folder.
for example I assume you created your project as follows :

```
svnadmin create /var/www/svn/mypro
```

=>mypro is your project.

go to /var/www/svn/ and delete the mypro folder completely.

and you will get rid of your project.